# Implement Objective c protocol in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, protocols

I have this protocol in a objective c class:

```
@protocol YTManagerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)uploadProgressPercentage:(int)percentage;
@end
...
```

and a swift class connected to it:

```
class YTShare: UIViewController, YTManagerDelegate{

    func uploadProgressPercentage(percentage:Int?){
        println(percentage)
    }
    ...
```

I receive the error: **type YTShare does not conform to protocol YTShareDelegate**, I have probably write incorrectly the swift function so the obj class don't find it. How I can write it correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two errors in the delegate method

```
func uploadProgressPercentage(percentage:Int?){
    println(percentage)
}
```

The parameter must not be an optional, and the C type `int` is mapped to Swift
as `CInt` (an alias for `Int32`):

```
func uploadProgressPercentage(percentage:CInt){
    println(percentage)
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `NSInteger` in the Objective-C protocol, which is
mapped to `Int` in Swift. This would be a 32-bit or 64-bit integer, depending
on the architecture, whereas `int`/`CInt` is always 32-bit.