# Passing dictionary objects to Objective C protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, dictionary, protocols

I'm trying to pass a dictionary object to an Objective C protocol using swift.

the protocol code snippet is as follows:

```
@protocol MessageDelegate

- (void)handleNewMessageArrived:(NSDictionary *)messageContent;

@end
```

and this is the swift class the implements the protocol:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MessageDelegate
{
 ...

 func handleNewMessageArrived(messageContent : NSDictionary!)
 {
  ...    
 }
}
```

But the build fails, and the error I get is:

"***the type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'MessageDelegate***"

I looked at [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753069/implement-objective-c-protocol-in-swift) but it deals with a specific object type.

is there an error in the way I declare\implement the delegate method? or in the way I assume the arguments are mapped in swift?

I'm new to Swift so any Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try implementing the method in your Swift class like this:

```
func handleNewMessageArrived(messageContent: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    // Handle the message
}
```

Comment: @sbooth I haven't spent much time with Swift. Can you explain why you have to make the messageContent parameter an anonymous pointer in Swift? It's not id type (the equivalent) in Objective-C.

Comment: @DuncanC The `messageContent` parameter is an implicitly unwrapped optional containing a Swift dictionary with `NSObject` keys and `AnyObject` values.  This corresponds closely to `NSDictionary` and is the result of Swift's automatic bridging.

Comment: So by default container objects like dictionaries are containers of a specific type (e.g. dictionary of strings?) Isn't an NSDictionary a concrete type, and a valid parameter in Swift though?

Comment: All Swift containers are type-safe (a good thing).  `NSDictionary` is also a valid type in Swift, but the Swift <-> Objective-C bridge converts the types automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In case of Swift 3, this is what you will need

```
func handleNewMessageArrived(messageContent: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {
    // Handle the message
}
```